# How do I transpose twitter data of a non trading day on the last available trading day? (python)

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, prediction, stock

For a school project I am predicting 'green' ETFs price movements with tweet sentiment and tweet volume related to climate change.

I predict with a lag of 1, so the predictions of Monday are made with the data of Sunday. The data of Sunday consists of the tweet data (volume & sentiment) of Sunday and the market data that is equal to the trading data of Friday, as there is no trading in the weekend. However for accurate predictions I need the twitter data of Sunday on the trading data of Friday.

My question: How do I get the tweet data (volume and sentiment) of a non trading day on the last available trading day? So i can then drop the weekend/holiday entries.

So my novice thoughts went something like: I need a formula, that looks for NaN's in the column df['adjusted close'] If the next value is NAN: look at next value: If the next value is not NAN: Select the 'sentiment' value corresponding to the NAN on that date. And use that to replace the value in 'sentiment ' corresponding to the the date before the NaN

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

date = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-01-20")

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date,
                   'tweet_volume': range(20),
                   'sentiment': range(20),
                   'adjusted close':  [0,'NaN',2,3,4,5,6,7,'NaN','NaN',10,11,12,13,'NaN','NaN','NaN',17,18,19]},
                   columns = ['date', 'tweet_volume', 'sentiment', 'adjusted close'])

df = df.set_index('date')
gives:
    tweet_volume    sentiment   adjusted close
date            
2021-01-01  0   0   0
2021-01-02  1   1   NaN
2021-01-03  2   2   2
2021-01-04  3   3   3
2021-01-05  4   4   4
2021-01-06  5   5   5
2021-01-07  6   6   6
2021-01-08  7   7   7
2021-01-09  8   8   NaN
2021-01-10  9   9   NaN
2021-01-11  10  10  10
2021-01-12  11  11  11
2021-01-13  12  12  12
2021-01-14  13  13  13
2021-01-15  14  14  NaN
2021-01-16  15  15  NaN
2021-01-17  16  16  NaN
2021-01-18  17  17  17
2021-01-19  18  18  18
2021-01-20  19  19  19

and i want:
    tweet_volume    sentiment   adjusted close
date            
2021-01-01  *1* *1* 0
2021-01-02  1   1   NaN
2021-01-03  2   2   2
2021-01-04  3   3   3
2021-01-05  4   4   4
2021-01-06  5   5   5
2021-01-07  6   6   6
2021-01-08  *9* *9* 7
2021-01-09  8   8   NaN
2021-01-10  9   9   NaN
2021-01-11  10  10  10
2021-01-12  11  11  11
2021-01-13  12  12  12
2021-01-14  *16* *16* 13
2021-01-15  14  14  NaN
2021-01-16  15  15  NaN
2021-01-17  16  16  NaN
2021-01-18  17  17  17
2021-01-19  18  18  18
2021-01-20  19  19  19

So I can then drop the rows with NaN's
```

Comment: Could you demonstrate what the output of this dataframe would look like? I'm a little confused, I confess.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214014/python-stock-prediction-how-to-replace-sentiment-values-on-fridays-with-sentim).

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
date = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01",end="2021-01-20")

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date,
                   'tweet_volume': range(20),
                   'sentiment': range(20),
                   'adjusted close':  [0,'NaN',2,3,4,5,6,7,'NaN','NaN',10,11,12,13,'NaN','NaN','NaN',17,18,19]},
                   columns = ['date', 'tweet_volume', 'sentiment', 'adjusted close'])
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)
df = df.set_index('date')

df[['tweet_volume','sentiment']] = df.groupby((df['adjusted close'].diff(0).notnull()).astype('int').cumsum()).transform('last')[['tweet_volume','sentiment']]
df = df.dropna()
print(df)
```

output:

```
            tweet_volume  sentiment  adjusted close
date
2021-01-01             1          1             0.0
2021-01-03             2          2             2.0
2021-01-04             3          3             3.0
2021-01-05             4          4             4.0
2021-01-06             5          5             5.0
2021-01-07             6          6             6.0
2021-01-08             9          9             7.0
2021-01-11            10         10            10.0
2021-01-12            11         11            11.0
2021-01-13            12         12            12.0
2021-01-14            16         16            13.0
2021-01-18            17         17            17.0
2021-01-19            18         18            18.0
2021-01-20            19         19            19.0
```

Comment: Thanks A bunch! Your code does indeed do what I want :).